# Any reason why log field should private static?

Tags: c#, java, actionscript-3

here is in C#:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (MyClass));
```

Not only in C# but another language i saw the same..
any thought?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's private because other classes should not access `MyClass`' log.

It's `static` because it doesn't depend on the class instance.  (And so that it can be used by `static` methods)

Comment: Would there be any performance loss if the field is not static? Or is it a matter of making it syntaticaly correct?

Comment: @jpartogi: If `GetLogger` is an expensive call, or if each `ILog` instance uses a lot of memory, definitely.  Otherwise, not much.

Answer (score 3):

So that the field isn't inherited by your sub-classes.

Take this example:

```
class BaseFoobar
{
   public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(BaseFoobar));
}

class SpecializedFoobar : BaseFoobar
{
   public void Whatever()
   {
      log.Error("I exploded");
   }
}
```

If `SpecializedFoobar`'s `Whatever()` function is ever called the co-responding log would be invalid:

`[MyApp.BaseFoobar]: ERROR: I exploded`

Comment: thanks for the complete explanation about inheritance problem, but sorry i should choose Slaks answer because he describe about the static too.